# Generic handling of typescript promise response/errors

Tags: typescript, error-handling, promise

I have a number of functions that all perform the exact same action upon the return of a promise. `this.client` is a wrapper for a set of API calls, they return a response or an error. I wish to handle these in all the same manner.

Any ideas can I reduce each of these methods into one liners?

```
  getHealthCheck() {
    return this.client.tools.healthcheck().then((response) => {
      return {success: true, result: response};
    }).catch((err) => {
      return {success: false, err: err };
    });;
  }

  createUser(data) {

    return this.client.users.create(data).then((response) => {
      return {success: true, result: response};
    }).catch((err) => {
      return {success: false, err: err };
    });;

  }

  createCardAccount(data) {
    return this.client.cardAccounts.create(data).then((response) => {
      return {success: true, result: response};
    }).catch((err) => {
      return {success: false, err: err };
    });;
  }

  createBankAccount(data) {
    return this.client.bankAccounts.create(data).then((response) => {
      return {success: true, result: response};
    }).catch((err) => {
      return {success: false, err: err };
    });;
  }

  makePayment(data) {
    return this.client.items.makePayment(data).then((response) => {
      return {success: true, result: response};
    }).catch((err) => {
      return {success: false, err: err };
    });;
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just lift the response into another type:

```
type Success<T> = {success: true, result: T};
type Failure = {success: false, err: Error};
type Result<T> = Success<T> | Failure;
const Result = {
  from<T>(promise: Promise<T>): Promise<Result<T>> {
    return promise
           .then(result => ({success: true, result}))
           .catch(err => ({success: false, err}));
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as so:

```
return Result.from(this.client.tools.healthcheck());
```

Comment: I was attempting to implement something similar, following the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

This is really change my approach in TS going forward. Really appreciate you sharing.

Comment: url deprecated, use this one for generics docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 3):

Your callbacks for success and error seems to be the same..
You could do:

```
successHandler = (response:any)=>{
     return {success: true, result: response};
     }
errorHandler = (error:any)=>{
     return {success: false, err: err };
     }
```

and for all your requests,

```
 getHealthCheck() {
    return this.client.tools.healthcheck().then(this.successHandler).catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

// other calls
```

Its DRY principle.